# Смена значений в уже оглашенных переменных JAVA

Tags: java, переменные, null, scanner

В языках программирования ещё совсем новичок.

Недавно, однако, решил сварганить некую текстовую программку.

По идее, человек, зашедший в программу, читает ряд сообщений, после задаёт значение переменной (для примера назовём её переменной типа `String name`)(делал, подключая `Scanner`)...

Дальше, перед человеком, задавшим значение переменной name должен пасть выбор: сменить значение переменной, или продолжить.

Пытался делать через цикл (`do{}while();`), подключал ещё один цикл (`if(){}`), задавая переменной name значение `null`, однако, безуспешно...

Надеюсь, на Вашу помощь, в этой теме...

**П.С.** Облазил с 10 сайтов, однако, ничего не нашел по этой теме (возможно, не заметил)

**П.П.С.** Если всё же каким-то чудом, найду необходимую информацию, а ответа так и не будет, добавлю её как ответ самостоятельно... (в виде кода)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно что-то вроде этого. Присвоение новых значений переменным идёт через =.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = null;
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Name = " + name);
            System.out.println("Input new name:");
            final String input = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("New name = " + input);
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue (c) or change name (n) to " + input + "? Or exit (exit)?");
            final String decision = scanner.nextLine();
            if ("c".equals(decision)) {
                continue;
            } else if ("n".equals(decision)) {
                name = input;
            } else if ("exit".equals(decision)) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong input!!! Try Again!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы забыли упомянуть, что присвоение новых значений переменным должно происходить посредством создания ещё одной переменной, присвоения ей какого-либо значения, и лишь после, присвоения значения от созданной нами в цикле переменной, той, которая будет использоваться вне цикла... (Хотя, это было передано в коде)...